# Store string literal to pass it as std::string

Tags: c++, logging, c++17

I have a set of logging functions that accept a `const std::string &` tag argument which is supposed to be the name of the calling class. To use these functions, I want to store a string literal for each of my classes, so I won't have to type the class name manually for each log call.

The problem is, I cannot find an ideal solution on how to store these string literals, so it will be both more or less efficient and won't require boiler plate code for each log call.

Here are the options I see, each of which is not perfect:

1. Store the tags as `static constexpr const char kTag[] = "ClassName"` inside each class -- this makes clang-tidy complain that I should use `std::array` instead.
2. Store the tags as `static constexpr std::array kTag{"ClassName"}` inside each class -- this cannot be implicitly converted into `std::string` and I have to write `kTag[0]` for each call to get a `char *`.
3. Store the tags as `static constexpr std::string_view kTag = "ClassName"` -- this also cannot be imlicitly converted into `std::string`.
4. I don't want to use `#define`s as I'm trying to follow Google C++ style guide which says that preprocessor directives should be avoided .
5. I don't want to use `std::string` to store tags for the same reason as `#define`s -- Google C++ style guide says that [static variables should be trivially destructible](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Static_and_Global_Variables).
6. I even considered creating macros that will take `typeid(*this).name()` and pass it as the tag, but this is a preprocessor directive, requires RTTI (which is more or less ok by me since the logging is for debug only), and, most importantly, this cannot be used in constructors.

What should I do? This seems like something trivial, but I just can't find a nice solution.

Comment: Tell clang-tidy to shut up and use 1?

Comment: `static constexpr std::string{"Classname"s};`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It should be note that `constexpr std::string` is only allowed inside constant expressions.

Comment: `std::string` have [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that take a "string view like" object. So using a `std::string_view` [is possible](https://godbolt.org/z/dGqh8zq85).

Comment: Why not inherit some simple class like `ClassLogger`, which you construct with the classname. It can also provide a logging function that passes the prefix for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It gives me `No viable conversion from 'const std::string_view' (aka 'const basic_string_view<char>') to 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>')` if I just pass a `std::string_view` tag as is. This requires an explicit conversion which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @paddy The way I see this would mean that a string would be stored separately for each object of a class instead of storing a single string for the entire class.

Comment: You should use `std::string_view` as the argument of your logger function.

Comment: @n.m. I cannot do that: internally these functions call `c_str()` on their `std::string` arguments.

Comment: "internally these functions call c_str() on their std::string arguments." oh no - so you're constructing a `std::string` just to get a `char const *`, potentially allocating if the log message is long, when you don't even need the allocation except that's just how the interface works? This is such an anti pattern - is it possible to change the logger interface to accept string_view instead? Even if it isn't (for legacy reasons) I would overload it on string_view and move the common functionality to a function that doesn't require allocation in its interface when it doesn't need it.

Comment: @SRNissen Going into details, when logging for a desktop environment, `std::string`s are used as they are, but when compiled for Android, the functions have to convert the strings into C-strings because that is what Android logging functions require.

Comment: What's wrong with `static constexpr const char* kTag = "ClassName"`?

Comment: Is this an internal logging library or are you using an external one? It sounds like it might be worth it to take some time to change it so there's no overload for `const std::string &` and instead only two overloads, for regular `string_view` and r-value `std::string&&`.

Comment: @SRNissen This is an internal logging implementation, I will consider this, thanks.

Comment: Why can't you define a `const std::string` inside every class which you want to log things from? Or even a `static const std::string`.

Comment: If you cannot use `std::string_view`, since the conversion constructor of `std::string` is explict, you could still wrap `std::string_view` in a custom object with a conversion to `std::string`: `class MyStringView
{
    std::string_view m_value;
public:
    template<size_t N>
    consteval MyStringView(char const (&value)[N])
        : m_value(value, N - 1)
    {
    }
    operator std::string() const
    {
        return std::string(m_value);
    }
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing `std::string` parameter with `std::string_view` and converting it to `std::string` if a C-string is required (as `std::string_view` is not guaranteed to be nul-terminated). Then I was able to use `static constexpr std::string_view kTag = "ClassName"` to store tags.